# Window mounted split air conditioner

Tags: mechanical-engineering, hvac, cooling

I was wondering if there are any window mounted split air conditioners in US market or anywhere else - One in which compressor and radiator hang out of the window and only evaporator is inside the room. I was able to pull up many patents from as early as 1938 with same idea but don't think a commercial product exist. Any thoughts why it could be so?

Here are some patents and more mentioned in their reference section:
https://www.google.com/patents/US6568201
https://www.google.com/patents/US2268451

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you would use it for.  Are you intending to run a split system with a window open?

Comment: from the patent "object of this invention is to provide a conditioning unit having a portion passing through the window but arranged .. to permit the window to be fully closed or fully opened without .. moving the conditioning unit away from the window"  Not a bad concept, but I would suppose the free market has not provided demand for such.  Undoubtedly it would cost significantly more than a compact window unit

Comment: Idea is to keep the window unblocked. Traditional window units blocks the window. Here is a similar patent from Whirlpool filed in 2001
https://www.google.com/patents/US6568201
Take a look at Fig 4 & 6
I wouldn't expect it be a lot more costly compared to a window a/c. An extra motor and some housing changes is all that it needs compared to window units. I would certainly buy one since I would love to keep my windows unblocked.

Comment: What do you mean by "unblocked"?  Also, why is a regular split AC system not sufficient?

Comment: A regular window A/C takes up substantial portion of window..right? This concept takes up minimal window space - just enough for the refrigerant tubes and electrical wires to pass through. Yes, split A/C is sufficient but it is not easy to mount compared to window A/C and are typically large > 10,000BTUs and heavy. A 5000 BTU split A/C with some accessories to mount it on a window, which an average consumer can setup would be an alternative.

Comment: There are in fact plenty of  "portable" (google portable ac) units that use hoses to move air in/out. You could obviously pass the hoses through a window. (In fact folks do just that with windows that wont support a traditional unit).  If you are thinking of actually splitting the unit and passing refrigerant lines through a window I think you'd have issues making a movable system sufficiently robust to contain the freon (My guess a pile of EPA red tape as well )

Comment: Along with what agentp said, I still don't really get why you would want to do this with a split unit.  Then you would have to leave the window open a crack; which is going to hurt the effectiveness of the unit potentially.  A 2 hose portable unit is probably a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: @agentp I don't want it to be portable. A permanent fixture flush to the wall is what I am looking for. A portable solution takes up floor space too with a huge visible hose which is an eyesore. 
JMac: Not really. A good seal can be easily achieved I think.

Comment: @Jean If you're going to permanently affix a unit, I don't see how it would be any easier to go through the window.  The only difference between what you're proposing and a split system is that you want to run your piping through a window instead of through a wall.  The thing is, now you have a window which is stuck ajar (or ajar and sealed).  It seems like it would look a lot worse than running a regular split through the wall, mounted so that you don't even have to see the tubing.  Technically you could buy a regular split unit and just run the pipes through the window if you really need to.

Comment: Agree.. A small split unit  will do, especially if it has the option to mount on a window.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are "saddle" or "hybrid" units which are basically as you describe. See, for example, the [SoleusAir WS3-06E-201](https://soleusair.com/index.php/products/).

[image: photo of SoleusAir air conditioner]

Answer (score 0):

We rented one back in 1988 to cool our computer room so they definitely make them. The coolant tubes were about 30 feet long and as flexible as hose pipes. I don't know if they used gas or water as the coolant. But the outdoor side was hung out of an open window.